# Excel datevalue

Tags: c#, excel, date

How do I convert a date string 2019-06-20T00:00:00+01:00 to an Excel date?
DATEVALUE returns #Value when I try this in Excel.

The date string comes from C# DateTime ToShortDateString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ToShortDateString()` use [`ToOADate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx).

Format the cell as Date and you should be all set.

Comment: This is not great since ToOADate returns a double, I guess I can just change the way I show this in Excel and I am done!

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you could just take everything to the left of the `T` character. If that date string was in cell A1 then:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("T",A1)-1))
```

Alternatively in VBA if the date string was stored in a variable called `sFoo`:

```
CDate(Left$(sFoo,Instr(sFoo,"T")-1))
```